# NodeMCU doesn't find PN532 board, even though arduino mega does

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I have a PN532 RFID reader that I need to connect a NodeMCU that has a ESP8266.
The situation is that the code compiles, uploads but the NodeMCu doesn't recognise the board. I used the sample code from the library got the same results from then I tried makin adjustments and still nothing

I was concerned that the PN532 wasn't working so i tested it on a arduino Mega 2560 and it worked flawlessly with the same code. I also tried reflashing the chip to make sure it works, changing the code, I changed up the wiring at least 15 times. Tried many pin combinations and it still didn't work.

The code is the sample from the library but here it is

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_PN532.h>
#include <Adafruit_I2CDevice.h>
// If using the breakout with SPI, define the pins for SPI communication.
#define PN532_SCK  (14)
#define PN532_MOSI (13)
#define PN532_SS   (5)
#define PN532_MISO (12)

// Use this line for a breakout with a software SPI connection (recommended):
// Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_SS);
Adafruit_PN532 nfc(PN532_SCK, PN532_MISO, PN532_MOSI, PN532_SS);
void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Hello!\n");

  Serial.println("Hello!");

  nfc.begin();

  uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! versiondata) {
    Serial.println("Didn't find PN53x board");
    delay(100); // usually there would be a wait(1) but it messed the nodemcu up...
  }
  // Got ok data, print it out!
  Serial.print("Found chip PN5"); Serial.println((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX); 
  Serial.print("Firmware ver. "); Serial.print((versiondata>>16) & 0xFF, DEC); 
  Serial.print('.'); Serial.println((versiondata>>8) & 0xFF, DEC);
  
  // configure board to read RFID tags
  nfc.SAMConfig();
  
  Serial.println("Waiting for an ISO14443A Card ...");
}


void loop(void) {
  uint8_t success;
  uint8_t uid[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };  // Buffer to store the returned UID
  uint8_t uidLength;                        // Length of the UID (4 or 7 bytes depending on ISO14443A card type)
    
  // Wait for an ISO14443A type cards (Mifare, etc.).  When one is found
  // 'uid' will be populated with the UID, and uidLength will indicate
  // if the uid is 4 bytes (Mifare Classic) or 7 bytes (Mifare Ultralight)
  success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, uid, &uidLength);
  
  if (success) {
    // Display some basic information about the card
    Serial.println("Found an ISO14443A card");
    Serial.print("  UID Length: ");Serial.print(uidLength, DEC);Serial.println(" bytes");
    Serial.print("  UID Value: ");
    nfc.PrintHex(uid, uidLength);
    Serial.println("");
    
    if (uidLength == 4)
    {
      // We probably have a Mifare Classic card ... 
      Serial.println("Seems to be a Mifare Classic card (4 byte UID)");
      
      // Now we need to try to authenticate it for read/write access
      // Try with the factory default KeyA: 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF
      Serial.println("Trying to authenticate block 4 with default KEYA value");
      uint8_t keya[6] = { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };
      
      // Start with block 4 (the first block of sector 1) since sector 0
      // contains the manufacturer data and it's probably better just
      // to leave it alone unless you know what you're doing
      success = nfc.mifareclassic_AuthenticateBlock(uid, uidLength, 4, 0, keya);
      
      if (success)
      {
        Serial.println("Sector 1 (Blocks 4..7) has been authenticated");
        uint8_t data[16];
        
        // If you want to write something to block 4 to test with, uncomment
        // the following line and this text should be read back in a minute
        //memcpy(data, (const uint8_t[]){ 'a', 'd', 'a', 'f', 'r', 'u', 'i', 't', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm', 0, 0, 0, 0 }, sizeof data);
        // success = nfc.mifareclassic_WriteDataBlock (4, data);

        // Try to read the contents of block 4
        success = nfc.mifareclassic_ReadDataBlock(4, data);
        
        if (success)
        {
          // Data seems to have been read ... spit it out
          Serial.println("Reading Block 4:");
          nfc.PrintHexChar(data, 16);
          Serial.println("");
          
          // Wait a bit before reading the card again
          delay(1000);
        }
        else
        {
          Serial.println("Ooops ... unable to read the requested block.  Try another key?");
        }
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.println("Ooops ... authentication failed: Try another key?");
      }
    }
    
    if (uidLength == 7)
    {
      // We probably have a Mifare Ultralight card ...
      Serial.println("Seems to be a Mifare Ultralight tag (7 byte UID)");
      
      // Try to read the first general-purpose user page (#4)
      Serial.println("Reading page 4");
      uint8_t data[32];
      success = nfc.mifareultralight_ReadPage (4, data);
      if (success)
      {
        // Data seems to have been read ... spit it out
        nfc.PrintHexChar(data, 4);
        Serial.println("");
        
        // Wait a bit before reading the card again
        delay(1000);
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.println("Ooops ... unable to read the requested page!?");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the pictures of the circuit:

https://ibb.co/6sk6kGf

https://ibb.co/3vZc88h

https://ibb.co/JzcJkKg

I am really desperate at the moments I will accept any help and I will post all the information if something more is needed.
Thank you

Comment: It works on Arduino Mega because the pin assignments you had in the sketch match the SPI pins on Arduino Mega, it however doesn't match the NodeMCU [SPI](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/release/modules/spi/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ESP8266 (Nodemcu) + PN532 (RFID) + ST7735 (Display) in one setup possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324180/esp8266-nodemcu-pn532-rfid-st7735-display-in-one-setup-possible)